# Firebug keeps randomly stopping in ExtJS

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints, firefox3.6

ExtJS 1.7.3 on FF 3.6 ² keeps stopping on this line 9863, every time I load my page:

```
9860 try{
9861 var ssRules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
9862   for(var j = ssRules.length-1; j >= 0; --j){
9863     rules[ssRules[j].selectorText.toLowerCase()] = ssRules[j];
9864   }
9865 }catch(e){}
```

just as if I had set a breakpoint. Pressing continue (F8) and everything goes on, just like with a breakpoint. But there 100% certainly is no such thing...

Huh? Anyone has any idea?

² no, I don't want to upgrade, I need to test under this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and fixed it like so:

1. Uninstall firebug in the firefox add-ons manager
2. Close firefox
3. rm -rf [profile_folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Navigating_to_the_profile_folder)/firebug
4. Delete all firebug-related lines from profile_folder/prefs.js
5. Reinstall firebug

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "stopping", do you mean in Firebug or something?  If so, do you just have break-on-exception enabled?

Comment: The "[||] breaks on next/all errors" is off. Not blinking. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.  In that case, that's a bit odd.  I assume you _are_ seeing it stop in Firebug?  Are any of the other special condition breakpoints Firebug lets you set (style changes, etc) enabled?

Comment: No. I didnn't. (Played with them right now in the HTML tab, there would be no comprehensive list like for script BP, if you ever set plenty of these, is there?)